# Can a static variable exist free of a class in C++?

Tags: c++

Can static variables exist anywhere in C++ other than in a class? If so, what behaviour do they exhibit? I assume they're not being shared between instances as there is no object.

Comment: if you downvote, say why - then I can improve the question. That's kind of the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The lifetime of a static object is the life of the program and the linkage of the object is internal if the variable is declared at file scope (and no linkage if defined at block scope).

Answer (score 1):

Outside of a function, static means local to that compilation unit. You can achieve the same effect with an anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, of course, for example:

```
int sequence()
{
    static int result = 0;
    return ++result;
}
```

So, here, the result variable will continue to exist outside the scope of the function and constantly increase every time you enter the function.

Answer (score 1):

Two other places:

1. Global variables and functions

   - Global `static` variables (or functions) are local to that compilation unit and cannot be "seen" from other compilation units
2. Local variables

   - `static` local variables are initialised once when their declaration is crossed for the first time (this is useful for doing things only on the first time a function is called), and after that they retain their value even after the function has returned and is called again

Note that these different uses of `static` really have nothing to do with each other. `static` means different things depending on where you use it, much like `const`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by a static variable. The `static` keyword has different semantics depending on the situation in which you use it.

Member variables, when declared as static, have static storage duration. This means the lifetimes of these variables lasts for the duration of the program. This is the common meaning of a 'static variable'. There are 3 cases under which a variable will have static storage duration:

1. When the `static` keyword is used on a local (function scope) variable.
2. When the `static` keyword is applied to a class member variable.
3. Any variable that does not have dynamic or thread storage duration and is not a local variable.

Example:

```
struct foo
{
  static int x; // This has static storage duration
};

void bar()
{
  static int y = 5; // This has static storage duration
}

int z = 1; // This has static storage duration
```

So to answer your question as if it were "Can variables have static storage duration when not members of a class?", the answer is yes. A global or namespace scope variable has static storage duration by default. A function scope variable declared as static also has static storage duration.

However, the `static` keyword has another meaning when it is used on variables in global or namespace scope. For these, `static` specifies that the variable has internal linkage. That is, they can only be referred to within the same translation unit.

Example:

```
static int i = 5; // This has internal linkage
```